# How to find mutiple words in textview for changing color of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, nsmutableattributedstring

I am working on project in which I took a texview and its delegate method below

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attstr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textView.text];
    NSUInteger characterCount = [attstr length];
    NSString *str = @"football";
    NSUInteger searchlength = [str length];
    NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(0, attstr.length);
    while (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        range1 =[attstr.string rangeOfString:str options:0 range:range1];
        if (range1.location !=NSNotFound) {
            [attstr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(range1.location, searchlength)];
            [attstr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]  range:range1];
            range1 = NSMakeRange(range1.location + range1.length, characterCount -(range1.location + range1.length));
            textView.attributedText = attstr;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in that method, I am finding keyword "football" and change its color to redcolor. Here I am searching for a single string, So what should I do for checking for multiple strings like array

My problem is How can I find multiple strings at a time into text of textview.

Please help me with it 
Thank you

Comment: You can wrap your code with a `for` loop through the elements in the array of words to be replaced. Perhaps not the best algorithm though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this thing like this

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attstr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textView.text];
    NSUInteger characterCount = [attstr length];
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"football",@"player",nil];

    for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {

    NSUInteger searchlength = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]] length];
    NSRange range1 = NSMakeRange(0, attstr.length);

    while (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
        range1 =[attstr.string rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:i]] options:0 range:range1];
        if (range1.location !=NSNotFound) {
            [attstr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(range1.location, searchlength)];
            [attstr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]  range:range1];
            range1 = NSMakeRange(range1.location + range1.length, characterCount -(range1.location + range1.length));
            textView.attributedText = attstr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is any other method which I can use Please do me a favour to it

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"football",@"player",@"match"];
```

---

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *text = textView.text;

    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];        

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0 ,text.length);
    NSRegularExpression *regex;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {
        NSString *obj = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:obj options:kNilOptions error:nil];// Case sensitive 

        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:text options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

            NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:0];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:subStringRange];
        }];

        txt_out.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I dont want this, I already achieve it. I want to change multiple strings color  in text of textview like I have an array "[football, player]" so when I type football or player its text change to redcolor.

Comment: @BhavinRamani I have already Solve it as my below answer. But thank you, I appreciate it